# My core 2 quad q6600 is 90c while in the bios (H/W monitor) (with intel stock cooler)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, overheating

So I just upgraded my motherboard to an MSI G31TM-P21 https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/G31TMP21.html But with this motherboard my core 2 quad q6600 hits 90 degrees C while in the bios, even when underclocked. It should support the CPU as on the page for it says "CPU (Max Support) Core 2 Quad" my core 2 duo E7200 works perfectly on it at 24 degrees C in the bios. What's going on? I pulled the CPU from a working system. And I have a reliable power supply (EVGA 600 watt 80+ bronze). The power supply is less than a month old.
I have reapplied the thermal paste multiple times as well as had a very experienced technician do so himself, still overheats in seconds. It also auto shuts down before I can boot windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely the cooler you are using for the CPU is not designed to handle the TDP (Thermal Design Power) of the newer processor.

You may want to investigate the TDP of the two processors and of your cooler.

Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7200 is 65W:
http://ark.intel.com/products/35348/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7200-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB

Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q6600 is 105W:
http://ark.intel.com/products/29765/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6600-8M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB

Comment: Sorry, I should I listed, I'm using a intel stock cooler

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with the older Core 2 series, but I have noticed a difference between the factory coolers packaged with first generation i3 and i7 processors. The i3 was much shorter, having less surface area for the fins on the heat sink, where as the i7 had a much taller one.

Comment: Yeah, I read online and it would seem the coolers have small variations across all of the generations, so that only leads to more confusion

Comment: When packaged at the factory, they will ship an appropriate cooler. It sounds like you are still using the same cooler from the much lower TDP processor for the higher one.

Comment: I am, I guess that's the issue, although would the cooler still be responsible with the core 2 quad severely underclocked? (I think I tested at 1.5 ghz)

Answer (score 2):

As @dark_st3alth mentioned above, it is not possible to mantain the correct temperature on the E7200 and Q6600. The wattage difference is very big.

From [here](https://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/573910-Q6600-vs-E6600-Stock-HSFs)

You can see that, although the size of the cooler+heatsink is similar, the fan power is different.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that's the only thing that makes sense to me .Thanks for @dark_st3alth and you, jgorosdev. I guess it's the cooler. I guess this only enforces the idea of my upgrading my motherboard, CPU, and ram as it's all old.